How to handle the git situation 'Your branch and 'origin/main' have diverged...'
Following is summary of the steps follows:

User A:

Clones the repo with one main branch.
Creates a new branch and commits a new file.
Publishes the branch and pushes the changes to the remote repo.


User B:

Clones the same repo and makes a change the the newly committed file under the same new branch
Commits the changes and pushes the changes to the remote repo.
Creates a pull request and merges the changes into the main branch following the approval process.
Now both branches the main and the test branches are the same on User B repo and the remote.


User A:

Switched to the main branch (if I remember correctly)
Ran the command git pull
Got the following output:
remote: Enumerating objects: 8, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (8/8), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (4/4), done.
remote: Total 5 (delta 1), reused 3 (delta 1), pack-reused 0
Unpacking objects: 100% (5/5), 991 bytes | 14.00 KiB/s, done.
From https://github.com/org-name/REPO-NAME
 f508df2..b93c3be  main          -> origin/main
 8e9820b..80b9af6  test-live-ghe -> origin/test-live-ghe
Auto-merging test.txt
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in test.txt
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.


Resolved the merge conflict (not sure if it was on the main or the new branch)
I can tell now a new commit is required but not sure why as I was expecting to get the changes from remote to override local.
Ran another git pull and got the following output:
error: You have not concluded your merge (MERGE_HEAD exists).
hint: Please, commit your changes before merging.
fatal: Exiting because of unfinished merge.


Ran git status and got the following output:
On branch main
Your branch and 'origin/main' have diverged,
and have 1 and 2 different commits each, respectively.
(use "git pull" if you want to integrate the remote branch with yours)
All conflicts fixed but you are still merging.
(use "git commit" to conclude merge)
Changes to be committed:
      modified:   test.txt





On User B, I was expecting to pull the changes from remote repo to local and no need to do a merge since the remote is ahead of the local.
The above situation doesn't look right. The question is, how to pull the changes and avoid creating a merge commit on local where applicable? What am I doing wrong?

I had to update my answer to expand the workflow section


how to pull the changes and avoid creating a merge commit on local where applicable? What am I doing wrong?

The main issue with your workflow is that you have multiple developers working locally on a same branch at the same time. A branch should be worked on only by one developer at a time. Otherwise, the development might split into different histories that need to be reconciled (liked happened to you).
Usually, you create a branch per feature. A single developer works on it, and when the feature is concluded, this is merged back with a Pull Request into the branch it diverged from, or into a development line called develop (see gitflow for more info). If someone else wants to contribute to the feature while this is being worked on, they need to create a separate branch.
In your case, if the divergence happened on the feature branch, it means that dev A kept working on it while B was making their changes. Instead, if the divergence happened on the main branch, either dev A merged feature into main locally in their repo (not with a PR), or made changes directly on the main branch. The best approach to handle this situation is to have the following branches: main, feature, feature-A, and feature-B.

main contains the main line of development. The solid tested version of the software that can be deployed on the production environment.
feature contains the contributions coming from multiple developers working on separate branches (not directly on feature).
feature-A is worked exclusively by developer A to implement the corresponding feature. This is often synced with the feature branch with a rebase. So, while on the feature branch, run git pull feature to retrieve its latest updates (won't cause any conflicts because nobody works directly on it). Then, select feature-A and run git rebase feature to rebase any local changes on feature-A on top of feature (this is to make sure that feature's latest changes are included in your local history). Lastly, every integration from feature-A to feature must happen via a Pull Request. In this scenario, you're leveraging the concept of remote as an authoritative basis for collaborative development, where every integration to a public branch always happens publicly with a PR, rather than with a local merge in somebody's repo followed by a push; this second approach is in fact prone to creating diverging histories.
feature-B works exactly like feature-A but with respect to developer B.

With this approach in mind, you are preventing to create diverging histories on a same branch. This does not mean that you won't have conflicts when rebasing feature-A or feature-B on top of feature. This approach grants you that on a same public branch (feature, main, or any other remote's branch) there will not be diverging histories across your developers' repositories.

Disclaimer: Since you don't remember if the divergence happened on main or feature, from now on, I'm assuming it happened on feature, but everything I am about to say applies to both.



Ran another git pull and got the following output:
error: You have not concluded your merge (MERGE_HEAD exists).


It seems like that after resolving all the conflicts at point 4, you did not stage the corresponding files and finalize the merge with a commit, since Git is telling you error: You have not concluded your merge (MERGE_HEAD exists). When you have a merge with conflicts, you need to resolve the conflicts, stage the conflicting files, and then create a commit to conclude the merge.



Ran git status and got the following output:


Here, Git is telling you that the local history of branch feature on developer A's machine has diverged from the one on the remote. Right now, you're still in the middle of a merge, and Git is asking you to resolve the conflicts caused by combining the two lines of development. A git pull is just a git fetch followed by a git merge.
Git can tell if two branches have diverged, if the head commit of both branches is not present in the other's history. In your case, the branch feature created by developer B and pushed to the remote contains commits Y and Z, while the local branch on developer A's machine continued with a different history of changes, creating commit X.
A -- B           main
     | \
     |  X        feature
      \
       Y -- Z    origin/feature

When developer A pulled from the remote, they basically fetched the changes into a tracking branch called origin/feature, and then merged origin/feature into feature, bringing you to your current situation.


On User B, I was expecting to pull the changes from remote repo to local and no need to do a merge since the remote is ahead of the local.

Technically, yes. But, if the merge hasn't been resolved properly, the two branches are still diverging. In your question, there are no steps of what happened after fixing the conflicts on developer A's machine. For what we know, the merge might have been ended with a quit (not abort or continue), and the changes left by the merge could have been integrated manually with a regular commit. In this scenario, there would be just another commit on top of dev A's history, which would not merge B's into A's, thus leaving the two branches still diverged.
Another scenario could be that the merge did happen successfully, but developer B created another commit while developer A was still merging the pull.

What to do when the local history diverges from the remote's history
When a local branch diverges from its remote counterpart, it's probably best to move the local commits to a different branch, reset the branch to where it diverged from, pull the new changes, and then bring the moved commits into the desired branch with a PR.
# pulling new changes and discovering that we diverged from the remote
git pull

# aborting the merge issued by git pull to restore the repo to the moment before the pull
git merge --abort

# create a new temporary branch with our diverging history
git checkout -b feature_temp

# selecting the feature branch
git checkout feature

# finding the commit where feature diverged from the remote's branch
git merge-base feature origin/feature

# resetting the feature branch to the commit where feature branched off
git reset --hard <commit-where-feature-diverged-from>

# pulling the new changes from the other developer into feature with a fast-forward
git pull

# selecting the temporary branch
git checkout feature_temp

# pushing the remporary changes to a new branch on the remote
git push

# creating a PR on GitHub from the temporary branch to feature


Thank you. I'll check it out and accept the answer accordingly!
